# AngularJS $promise is undefined only inside a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I don't know how to describe my problem and how to ask what do I want? I experienced strange thing with `AngularJS`. I hope you will understand it by reading the below code snippet. Please inform me if I need to clarify some thing.

In very short :
The same thing is `working` and `not-working`.

```
(function(){

    angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])

    .factory('Post', function($resource){

        return $resource('/user/:userId/posts/:id', {'userId':'@creator','id':'@_id'}, {
            update : {method:'PUT'}
        });

    })

    .controller('PostController', 
    ["$scope", "Post",
    function($scope, Post){

        $scope.updatePost = function(data, params) {
                    //When I call this method 
            //This raises error that says:
            //Post.update(...).$promise is undefined
            Post.update(params, data).$promise.then(function(res){
                console.log(res);
            });
        }


        //This is working
        Post.update({userId:'me', id:1}, {content:'Some modified content.'}).$promise.then(function(res){
            console.log(res);
        });

    }]);

})();
```

**UPDATE**
Below is a log for both `working` and `not-working` things :

When working  - console.log(Post.update(...)) results :

```
$promise
    Object { then=function(), catch=function(), finally=function()}

$resolved
    true

content
    "Some modified Content"

$delete
    function()

$get
    function()

$query
    function()

$remove
    function()

$save
    function()

$update
    function()

__proto__
    b { $get=function(), $save=function(), $query=function(), more...}
```

When working -  console.log(Post.update(...)) results :

```
catch
    function()

finally
    function()

then
    function()
```

Comment: Did you debug and inspect the result of Post.update(params, data)? In your example it is not clear what post is (which you use in ng-click="updatePost" ...). Can you create a jsfiddle which reproduces it?

Comment: The one difference I see is: working Post you call immediately after controller is created with hard coded data. The "not-working" way, call from function with arguments. Please be sure that you provide to method proper parameters: aka `data, params`

Comment: Try to reproduce it in a jsfiddle, otherwise it will be hard to help you. Analyze the PUT-Request that is executed in the developer console of yout browser to see if it the same on both methods.